# ¿cómo obtener el valor de cada fila en una variable diferente en PHP de MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

¿Como puedo obtener el valor de cada fila en una variable de PHP desde MySQL? En la columna: grupo_completo tengo 5 filas con grupo1 y 3 filas con grupo2. Me gustaría obtener; $variable1 = grupo1  $variable2 = 5 $variable3 = grupo2 $variable4 = 3.

```
   $resultado = $conexion->query("SELECT grupo_completo, COUNT(*) as participantes 
   FROM juego GROUP BY grupo_completo;");
   while ($fila = $result3->fetch_row()) {
   $variable1 = $fila[0];
   $variable2 = $fila[1];
   $variable3 = $fila[0];
   $variable4 = $fila[1];
   }
```

¿como puedo obtener este resultado o como puedo obtener capturar en una variable cada fila?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No tiene demasiado sentido hacer lo que pides, pues vas a tener variables demasiado cripticas para trabajar con ellas después.

Planteate mejor hacer algo así:

```
$resultado = $conexion->query("SELECT grupo_completo, COUNT(*) as participantes FROM juego GROUP BY grupo_completo;");
$grupos_y_participantes = [];
while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
    $grupos_y_participantes[$fila['grupo_completo']] = $fila['participantes'];
}
```

porque haciendolo así, vas a crear un array asociativo denominado `$grupos_y_participantes` al cual podrás acceder mediante una llamada a su clave, por ejemplo:

```php
echo "Participantes de grupo1 son: ".$grupos_y_participantes['grupo1'];
```

lo cual facilitará su manejo posterior en otras partes de tu código.

Otro ejemplo sería este, para conseguir toda la lista de una vez:

```
foreach ($grupos_y_participantes as $grupo => $participantes) {
    echo "Los participantes del ".$grupo." son un total de ".$participantes."<br>\n";
}
```

**Resumen de cambios:**

1. He inicializado la variable **$grupos_y_participantes** definiendola como un array vacio, que durante el *while* se irá rellenando:

```
$grupos_y_participantes = [];
```

2. He sustituido el **fetch_row()** por **[fetch_assoc()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)** para poder llamar a los campos por su nombre y no un número, quedando el código más claro para futuras revisiones o lecturas.
3. En cada ciclo se va a ejecutar el relleno de la variable inicializada antes, mediante esto:

```
    $grupos_y_participantes[$fila['grupo_completo']] = $fila['participantes'];
```

donde la clave de cada elemento del array, ahora asociativo, **$grupos_y_participantes** se corresponde con `[$fila['grupo_completo']]`, siendo su valor `$fila['participantes']`.

Comment: ¡Genial! Muchas gracias. Ya me funciono. Saludos

Comment: Perfecto :-)  Saludos!